# I need to create a delay in a batch-file which varies between two given numbers

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a Batch-File wich opens another Program then waits and closes the previously opened Program.
The Problem is, it is necessary that the batch-file waits a different amount of time each time it's opened. 
e.g.

```
start "Your_Program_here"
timeout 20
taskkill /f /im "Your_Program_here"
```

The example above works, but has the same delay each time.
How can i get it to vary?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to wait the time so the first process finish its execution? or is just a simple thread.sleep because you want it?

if that's the case, I've successfully used a trick using a self ping

```
 ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul
```

the number next to -n is the seconds you want to wait.

Comment: i need it to start the program, then wait and end the program. the program does what it should automatically. I need the batch file to regulate how long the Program is doing it's stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%RANDOM%`:

```
start "Your_Program_here" timeout %random% taskkill /f /im "Your_Program_here"
```

> %RANDOM% generates a random integer from 0 to 32,767 (inclusive)
>
> 0 ≤ %RANDOM% ≤ 32767

You can also scale this range to suit your needs by multiplying (or dividing) `%RANDOM%` by another number.

([source](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html))

Answer (score 1):

you need to create algorithm that runs program then close in d/t time

and in this code ,you have to create a file which contain a files to open .name it "file.lst"

```
@echo off
setlocal
set f=0
set s=0
set d=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type file.LST') do (set /a f=f+1 &&::%%a)
:s
set /a d=d+3 &::you can replace 3 as any number that you wanna to be rate
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (file.LST) do (if not "%f%"=="%s%" (
start "" %%b 
set /a s=s+1
timeout %f%
taskkill /im %%b /f
)
)
goto s
```

thanks #naty